# Undefined method flash in the view of node.js

Tags: node.js, locomotivejs, node.js-client

Problem in accessing `flash` `messages` on view in `node.js`
In my Controller

```
this.req.flash('info','successfully submited');
this.redirect("/home");
```

In my home view I am not able to get `flash` `messages` as

```
req.flash('info');
```

**EDIT**
**In controller**

```
self.req.flash('message','hello');
```

**In view**

```
<%= req.flash('message) %>
```

**In server.js**

```
app.configure(function (){

  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret:'yoursecret',cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }}));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(locomotive.session());
  app.use(flash());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);

  app.dynamicHelpers({ messages: require('express-messages') });
});
```

I have the locomotive framework.

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to help.  Are you correctly requiring `connect-flash`?  Did you use it with `app.use(flash)`?  What else have you tried?

Comment: yes i have added app.use(flash) in server.js and also used connect-flash. problem comes in view when i use flash().error comes that undefined method flash().

Comment: Can you post that code?  If that's the problem and it isn't in the question, there's not much we can do to help.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see tempdata example https://github.com/MKxDev/TempData

```
var tempData = require('tempdata');
    var app = express();

    app.configure(function() {
        ...

        // This has to appear BEFORE the router
        app.use(express.cookieParser());
        app.use(express.session({ secret: 'your_super_secret_session_key' })); // please change this!
        app.use(tempData);

        ...
    });

    ...

    // Routes
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        // Retrieve tempData value here. It won't exist unless the request
        // was redirected
        var tempVal = JSON.stringify(req.tempData.get('test_val'));

        res.render('index', { title: 'Express', temp: tempVal });
    });

    app.post('/', function(req, res) {
      // Set tempData value here
        req.tempData.set('test_val', { x: 'Hello World!' });

        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `app.use(flash())` higher in the order...see below.  Flash needs to be initialized before passport so that flash is recognized and available to passport.

```
app.configure(function (){
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret:'yoursecret',cookie: { maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }}));
  app.use(flash()); // moved this up a few lines
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(locomotive.session());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.dynamicHelpers({ messages: require('express-messages') });
});
```

Comment: sir,still error comes in view that undefined flash() method

Comment: In the view? Ahhh...  First, is there a typo in your view?  There's a typo in the question regarding the view that I didn't notice - a missing single-quote. Second, how are you passing `req.flash` to the view?  Are you setting `self = this` at some point?

Comment: Matt Bakaitis yes i m setting self=this and req.flash